# How to dynamically import non-component node_modules in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

Suppose you have a client-side library that you want to use in your Next.js project, such as Crunker which uses the browser's audio APIs.

In next.js, you can't import it like normal.

You also can't import it using `dynamic` because `dyncmic` is only for components.

You also can't import it using something like `const packageDynamic = (await import('npm-package')).default;` because you can't await at the top level.

You can't import it in a useEffect and store it in a useState because the type for the class is the class itself, and you have to import it to have access to that type. Even if you could, it is bad programming because a) now your imports are not located in one place anymore, which is bad readability, b) it needlessly clutters your effects, and c) it's way more code than is necessary, so it's just a bad solution overall.

Given all of the above, the question is: how does one accomplish this? If it's not possible in Next.js, that would make me seriuosly reconsider how good this framework actually is.